# Opening Screenshot in capture menu not in the action menu!

Tags: xubuntu, screenshot, ubuntu-studio, xfce-panel

I have added ScreenShot to the xfce-pannel but like starting it using [Fn] [Prnt Scrn],  I don't get the timelaps option, instead I get the full screen capture menu, but opening the same Screenshot from the Application menue I get this:

This is what I want:[image]

But this full screen capture menu is what I get:
[image]

Where do I change the xfce-pannels setting for Screenshooter, and where do I find them?

It seems I can get the menu-alas defunkt by rightclick and choose proberties:
[image]
But this have no OK button!
[image]
Only the close, there must be a way to rectify this!
Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the pannel properties window really dos something!
It saves the settings chosen for further use, so now it chooses the active window with a delay of 4 seconds, which is ample to open right-click menues and possition the curser!

The [PrntScrn] button [Fn] [F10]/[F11] on my labtop is configured from the 
settings menu - settings Editor - xfce shortcuts.!

[image]

By remowing the -f flag I get the Pick-menu, not just the save menu.